# asp.net gridView - responsive webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms, responsive

I created a GridView that is somewhat responsive. After i scale the browser to a certain point it doesnt stack like it would on a mobile device. what do i need to add to my gridViews to get them to display nicely on a mobile device?

```
        <section id="no-more-gridView">
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" CssClass="table table-bordered table-hover table-responsive-xl w-100 align-self-auto" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Height="296px" Width="886px" AllowSorting="True" BorderStyle="Groove" HorizontalAlign="Center" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCFFFF" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Row#" HeaderText="Row#" SortExpression="Row#" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Number" HeaderText="Number" SortExpression="Number" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Person" HeaderText="Person" SortExpression="Person" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Reason" HeaderText="Reason" SortExpression="Reason" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Type" HeaderText="Type" SortExpression="Type" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
            </Columns>
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="table table-primary"/>
        </asp:GridView>
        </section>
```

Comment: If you want a responsive site then you probably shouldn't use `asp` controls. If it is an option, you shouldn't use webforms at all.

Comment: If you use a Repeater control to dynamically build your HTML markup instead of relying on a GridView, you'll have a lot more control over the rendered HTML and can easily integrate any responsive CSS framework. Of course like Crowcoder said, at that point you may as well not be using Web Forms. Oh - and I see you're using SQL Data Source. You really shouldn't use those. Database connections do not belong in your Web Forms. That's not conducive to following Separation of Concerns and is going to lead to a difficult to test architecture.

Comment: Not at all convinced that dumping asp.net web forms and asp.net controls you going to by  some magic get a more responsive page with less or more efforts. The default for asp.net + web form pages has been for YEARS to include the responsive bootstrap framework by default. I mean, this question could be change to how can i get a table to better collapse for smaller screens - and that gridview/listview/repeater winds up rending the content in a <tr> and standard HTML table anyway.  So, the poser could have just well asked how to make a table collapse better, and answers to that would apply here.

Answer (score 0):

As noted, by defualt, bootstrap should be working.

To allow that gridview to REALLY crunch down, and re-size REALLY nice?

I suggest this:

class="table table-hover table-fixed">

The fixed really does a great job - it seeks to try and fix the column sizes.

Thus on a 1920 BIG monitor, I get this:

[image]

But, resized as VERY small - easy to fit on a phone? You get this:

[image]

Now we gone from 1920 down to 517 pixels.

I don't think you can get much better crunching down then say the above. And if you need smaller yet, then I don't think bootstrap or any responsive framework going to help you all that much.

So, I did above with this:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" class="table table-hover table-fixed">
```

I do find that table-fixed seems to do about the best here, but you could try a few other settings:

Say this:

```
class="table table-responsive"
```

So give both a try. The last one is quite much what most use - and it also does a really great job at re-sizing.